# P/Inoke catching native exception

Tags: pinvoke

I am testing a C# .NET 4.0 application which interacts with an C++ unmanaged DLL through PInvoke and I'd like to catch any exceptions thrown by the dll.
I have the dll function wrapped in try/catch clause to handle the native exception, but when it gets fired it is ignored. Tried :

```
try { } catch {}
try {} catch (Exception)
try {} catch (SEHException)
try {} catch (Win32Exception)
```

to no avail

The only option that works is by setting the *DllImport SetLastError* property to true and
after calling the function checking with :

```
if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() !=0)
```

It is a satisfactory solution but I just wonder why the other options do not have any effect as well as wonder if if the native exception is fired by the unmanaged dll or by the Windows API itself since for example the exception is a :

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): There is not enough space on the disk
```

is that a notification from the Windows API itself ?

Comment: What kind of DLL throws exceptions? That's exceptionally unusual. Are you sure that the DLL really does throw?

Comment: you are correct.What I do is `if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() !=0)   throw new Win32Exception();` so I actually throw the exception myself

Comment: You are throwing the error and you are also asking us what the error means. You threw it. You should know. How can we tell?

Comment: I did not ask what the error is, but how can I catch it without having to reside to `if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() !=0)`.

Comment: The answer to that question is found in the very first sentence of @Hans's answer. You cannot catch that which was never thrown in the first place!

Comment: yes @Hans made it clear before you asked.So since you've asked I am repeating it

Comment: I would also comment that I suspect your use of the Win32 last error is incorrect. It sounds like you are calling a 3rd party native DLL. It's highly unlikely that DLL is returning status using Win32 last error. Hans mentioned that also. Even if it is doing so, you should only ever check Win32 last error if the function in question has indicated failure in some other way, and also states in its interface contract that Win32 last error will be meaningful. It's common for functions to succeed and yet leave Win32 last error non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple explanation is that the native code just doesn't throw an exception.  And yes, using GetLastWin32Error() is boiler plate for any Windows api function.  Other code might use it too, although it isn't terribly common, anybody can call SetLastError() to set the thread's error code.  C code otherwise never intentionally throws exceptions, the language doesn't support it.

The 0x80004005 error code is COM error code, E_FAIL.  You don't use pinvoke to call COM functions, the CLR's support for COM interop takes care of it through an import library.  You *do* get exceptions for COM errors, the CLR throws them when it sees that the COM method returned a failure code.  It also uses IErrorInfo to get a better description for the error code, returned in the Exception.Message property.

Comment: thanks very much for concise answer,once more.Could you tell me what the difference between a Win32Exception and a SEHException is?

Comment: A Win32Exception is a specific exception that only raised by managed code and used to signal the failure of a winapi call.  Same idea as the exception raised when a COM call fails, an error code converted to an exception.  An SEHException is a raised when native code throws an unmanaged exception.  Caught by the marshaller and converted to a managed exception.  Never catch an SEHException, it is always bad news.  Catching a Win32Exception is fine.

Comment: _A Win32Exception is a specific exception that only raised by managed code_ That makes it very clear

Comment: _The 0x80004005 error code is COM error code, E_FAIL._ I get this error when I do `if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() !=0) throw new Win32Exception();` More specifically _There is not enough space on the disk_ which corresponds to System Error 112 (0x70). Is that a Win32 or a COM error? Or maybe the Win32 error is translated into a COM exception?